# Terminology introduced in recent years with more than one meaning

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, big-list, terminology

Suppose a term(inology) is recently (in last 20 years) introduced in research mathematics.

It might happen that some one who wish to use it, in **the same area of research**, for different purposes or see from different point of view realize that, some condition needs to be added or removed for their pov/purpose but still calling by **the same name**. This creates a slight confusion.

> What are some term(inology) introduced recently (in last 20 years) which have more than one possible meaning because of different point of view or different purpose?

Comment: This is not just for examples from tagged areas. As number of tags are restricted to 5, I have to choose five, I could only choose 4 :) Examples from other areas are also welcome.

Comment: There was a slight confusion in the context of the question.. I edited it to make it clearer.. If there is still some confusion on what I am interested in, please leave a comment here...

Comment: Even in ordinary language, words can have many meanings, with some related, and some not.  So it's not surprising that this happens in math also.

Comment: @DonuArapura Hello Sir. Yes, it is not surprising, it is only confusing :)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/286732/93602

Comment: More of a comment than an answer: the use of the word "deformation" in algebraic geometry to mean (depending by the context) "infinitesimal deformation", "flat deformation", simply "deformation" or even sometimes "(mild) degeneration".

Sometimes there is not a big difference for practical purposes, but there can be misunderstandings and confusion (for example when some invariants are not at all preserved)

Comment: @Enrico Please see if you can get some time to make it as an answer... you can write 1 or 2 lines of explanation with some references.. That would be good..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I do not remember any specific reference off the top of my head (this is way I wanted to keep this as a comment). However, if I happen to find one, I will put it as an answer.

Comment: @polfosol Thanks for the link.. I have not seen that before.. I am only concerned about recently introduced terms... About terms which are older than 20 or so years there is already some understanding of what it is saying... It would take some time for terms with different meanings to stay together. :D Thus, I kept that bound of ~20 years

Comment: @Enrico ok. no problem. Thank you :)

Comment: I would prefer this without any subject tags (it seems to value at.algebraic-topology above mg.metric-geometry, for no particularly good reason). The tags soft-question and big-list would be appropriate instead.

Comment: @MattF. edited.

Comment: Voting to close as this seems to me like the bad kind of big-list question: limitless potential examples, no clear criteria for the best ones, and no great usefulness in such a big indiscriminate collection of examples.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine It is useful to beginning grad students (at least).. Answers to this question are expected to clear some confusion regarding the terminology... I can not defend more..

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this terminological issue is as recent as you ask for, or arises in exactly the way you describe, but let me give the example anyway.

- The *index* of an algebraic variety $X$ with canonical (Weil) divisor $K_X$ is the smallest natural number $n$ such that $nK_X$ is a Cartier divisor. An example of this usage is in [this paper of Fujino](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9909035.pdf).

But also:

- The *index* of a nonsingular algebraic variety $X$ with canonical (Cartier) divisor $K_X$ is the largest natural number $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} K_X$ is a Cartier divisor. An example of this usage is in [these notes of Debarre](https://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/ExposePoitiers2013.pdf).

Alright, the former sense is only of use for singular varieties, while the latter is used in practice more or less only in the context of smooth (Fano) varieties. Still, it makes me scratch my head that the same word applied in two adjacent contexts in algebraic geometry has two essentially opposite meanings.

Comment: There is another meaning for the index of a variety here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2828.pdf

Comment: This seems to be strange :) Thanks for the answer.. Hope this would be helpful for people studying "index of an algebraic variety" for the first time...

Comment: Title for @HailongDao's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361995/terminology-introduced-in-recent-years-with-more-than-one-meaning#comment912660_362005):  [Gabbeer, Liu, and Lorenzini - The index of an algebraic variety](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2828).

Comment: Easily solved: "Weil index", "Cartier/Fano index"  :-)

Answer (score 8):

One example that I've seen is the use of the word "synthetic," which has multiple uses in differential geometry.

1. There is a field called synthetic differential geometry, which studies differential geometry from the viewpoint of topos theory. This is based off work of Lawvere, and popular among the more categorically minded; the ncat lab describes it [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/synthetic+differential+geometry).
2. There is also a field of synthetic differential geometry, mentioned by Matt F, "in a totally different tradition more closely connected to foundations of math and Finsler geometry." In that tradition Herbert [Busemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Busemann) is the founding figure; [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/346560/44143) are some sample results.
3. There is a separate idea known as synthetic curvature. This approach is based in analysis and uses ideas from convex analysis to understand curvature for spaces which are not necessarily smooth. This usage I'm a bit more familiar with and can give a few more details.

The analogy is that we can define convexity for a smooth function in terms of its Hessian being non-negative-definite. However,  for less smooth functions, we can define convexity by saying the function lies below all of its secant lines. The latter is a "synthetic" definition of convexity, and is more general.

Following this analogy, we can use the same approach in differential geometry. For instance,  it's possible to give synthetic definitions for sectional curvature bounds (e.g. the $CAT(\kappa)$ inequality) which make sense for geodesic spaces. Furthermore, one interesting insight from optimal transport is that it provides synthetic versions of Ricci lower bounds that make sense on metric-measure spaces. One good reference is this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0222). Another good reference is Villani's  survey [paper](https://www.cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2015/07/takagi-2.pdf)

In my experience, there aren't too many collisions between the first and third definitions because one originates from a categorical viewpoint and the other from an analytic perspective. In Matt F's experience, there aren't too many collisions with the second definition because Busemann's overall approach, despite coming earlier, never attracted many followers.

Comment: I thank you for your answer.. I was actually looking for terms which have different meaning but used in same area of research.. As your answer says the word "synthetic" is used in different areas of mathematics... There are many such words. I do not know if they create any confusion as they are in a completely different set up.. Sorry for the unclear question.. I have edited it now...

Comment: Fair enough. Just to clarify, both of these usages are in differential geometry, they just have different origins. To be fair, there probably isn't much confusion because there is some distance between them in the literature, as it were.

Comment: Thanks for taking my comment positively.. :)

Comment: @GabeK, there is confusion -- you are talking about Lawvere-style synthetic differential geometry, while there are multiple books by Busemann about synthetic differential geometry in a totally different tradition more closely connected to foundations of math and Finsler geometry. It's not recent, but it's still a problem for the few among us who like both.

Comment: I was only aware of Lawvere-style synthetic geometry and Villani-style synthetic curvature. I'm somewhat alarmed to find that there is a third definition which I didn't know about. I'll edit the answer to acknowledge your point.

Comment: 4 upvotes says that I have misunderstood something :D Thanks for the edit. It now looks relevant to the question :)

Answer (score 5):

The word “topological stack” has at least three usages:

1. A stack $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \text{Top}$ is said to be a topological stack  if there is a a morphism of stacks $p: \underline{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ for some manifold $M$, such that $p$ is a representable epimorphism. This is Definition 2.22, page number 86 in David Carchedi’s [thesis](http://math.gmu.edu/~dcarched/Thesis_David_Carchedi.pdf).
2. A stack $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \text{Top}$ is said to be a topological stack if there is a morphism of stacks $\underline{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ for a manifold $M$, such that $p$ is representable and has local sections. This is Definition $2.3$, page number 7 in Jochen Heinloth’s [Notes on Differentiable stacks](https://www.uni-due.de/~hm0002/stacks.pdf).
3. A stack $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \text{Top}$ is said to be a topological stack  if there is a a morphism of stacks $p: \underline{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ for some manifold $M$, such that $p$ is a representable epimorphism and that it is a “local fibration”. This is Definition $13.8$, peg number $42$ in Behrang Noohi’s [Foundations of topological stacks, I](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503247.pdf).

There maybe more. Feel free to add if you know more.

Answer (score 3):

My vote is for the phrase "***normal Cayley graph***".

Recall that a Cayley graph Cay($G$,$C$) is obtained from a group $G$ and a subset of its elements $C \subseteq G$. The vertex set of Cay($G$,$C$) is $G$ itself, and for each $g \in G$ and $c \in C$ there is an edge from $g$ to $gc$.

Some of my colleagues and co-authors say that Cay($G$,$C$) is a normal Cayley graph if $G$ is a normal *subgroup* of Aut(Cay($G$,$C$)).

Another set of colleagues and co-authors say that Cay($G$,$C$) is a normal Cayley graph if $C$ is closed under conjugation, (so that $C$ is like a normal *subset* of $G$).

The first usage involves looking *outside* $G$ while the second usage involves looking *inside* $G$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not *quite* a direct conflict of terminology, but it is a confusing near conflict of terminology, and it happened in the past twenty years:

- The *generalized permutohedra* are a class of convex polytopes introduced and studied by Postnikov in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507163; their defining property is that their normal fans are a coarsening of the normal fan of the permutohedron (i.e., the braid arrangement). (In fact, these polytopes had essentially already been studied for many years under the name *polymatroids*.) One of the most important examples of a generalized permutohedron, beyond the permutohedron itself, is the *associahedron* (see the title of Postnikov's paper).
- The *generalized associahedra* are a class of convex polytopes introduced and studied by Fomin and Zelevinsky in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111053. They come from the theory of *cluster algebras*. Specifically, the *cluster complex* is a simplicial complex that explains how all the clusters in a cluster algebra fit together. The cluster algebras of finite type (i.e., the ones with finite cluster complexes) are in bijection with root systems. The *generalized associahedron* of a root system is the polytope which is dual to the cluster complex of this root system. This name comes from the fact that in Type A, the generalized associahedron is the usual associahedron.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I am not sure if this fits in the set up of the question.. These are two different terms, so, I am not able to see the confusion.. I will leave it to the other users to decide if this is ok for the question..

Comment: Probably 'generalised' anywhere in a term is a warning that one should be on the lookout for potential ambiguities, given the number of axes along which one can generalise ….

Comment: @LSpice: yes, I think that is the lesson here.